# Blocking a site from myself and redirecting

Tags: hosts, hosts-file

I've tried editing "C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts" by adding:

```
127.0.0.1 websitetoblock.com
```

But I can still access the website. Ideally I want to be redirected to a URL of my choice if I try to access the other one. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to do this at a system level (so for everyone who uses the computer) or at a browser level (for someone who uses chrome, for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flush the DNS resolver cache.  No need to reboot to do this; at the command prompt, type:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

The hosts file cannot be used for HTTP URL redirection.

Comment: Yeah, I could not remember the flushing command. If he did reboot, that would of course work as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine. Try restarting the computer. The name is probably already resolved and cached.

Answer (score 0):

edit the hosts file as follows.

74.125.236.165 http://www.facebook.com

if you edited your host file like this, when you go to fb u will be redirected to google.com